# How to pass values to asp pages from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I am trying to pass a value from Javascript to ASP pages. But it can't run properly.

This is my Javscript:

```
function btn_upgrade_onclick() {

            var dlr = document.getElementById("<%txt_sapcode.ClientID%>").value;
            var dlrname = document.getElementById('<%=tex_dealername.ClientID %>').value;
            var addr1 = document.getElementById('<%=txt_addr1.ClientID %>').value;
            var addr2 = document.getElementById('<%=txt_addr2.ClientID %>').value;
            var addr3 = document.getElementById('<%=txt_addr3.ClientID %>').value;
            var mobno = document.getElementById('<%=txt_mob.ClientID %>').value;
            
             var stat = document.getElementById('drp_state').value;

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "DealerDetails.aspx/UpdateDealer",
                data: "{DlrId:'" + dealerID + "',DlrCode:'" + dlr + "',DlrName:'" + dlrname + "',Dlrad1:'" + addr1 + "',Dlrad2:'" + addr2 + "',Dlrad3:'" + addr3 + "',DlrMob:'" + mobno + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#drp_support").get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $("#drp_support").get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "0");
                    $("#drp_support").unbind("change");

                    $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                        $("#drp_support").get(0).options[$("#drp_support").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);

                    });

                    $("#drp_support").bind("change", function () {
                        sprtengId = $(this).val();
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        }
```

And the value are passed to the function

## region update

```
[WebMethod]
public static DataSet UpdateDealer(Int32 DlrId,Int32 DlrCode,string DlrName,string Dlrad1,string Dlrad2,string Dlrad3,Int16 Dlrddd,Int32 DlrLan,Int32 DlrMob)
{
    DataSet update = new DataSet();
    try
    {
      update=obj.UpdateDealerDetails(DlrId,DlrCode,DlrName,Dlrad1,Dlrad2,Dlrad3,DlrMob);
    }
    catch {}
    return update;
}
 

#endregion
```

When I press the **Update** button, it will call the Javascript function and then it passes the value in the text boxes to the ASP code `UpdateDealer();`

Before am writing this function in Javascript all other functions worked properly but now it's not working properly

Comment: Please check for any syntax error in your script if other worked functions are not working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your first line of js.

```
var dlr = document.getElementById("**<%**txt_sapcode.ClientID%>").value;
```

Fix this (= missing) and check.

Where have you defined, dealerID

```
data: "{DlrId:'" + dealerID + "',DlrCode:'" + dlr
```

also, i dont' think your stat variable is initialized with following line of code just confirm.

```
var stat = document.getElementById('drp_state').value;
```

Make sure you debug and variables you have defined are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

remove   static from

> public DataSet UpdateDealer(Int32 DlrId, Int32 DlrCode, string
>   DlrName, string Dlrad1, string Dlrad2, string Dlrad3, Int16 Dlrddd,
>   Int32 DlrLan, Int32 DlrMob)
>           {
>               DataSet update = new DataSet();
>               try
>               {
>                   update = obj.UpdateDealerDetails(DlrId, DlrCode, DlrName, Dlrad1, Dlrad2, Dlrad3, DlrMob);
>               }
>               catch { }
>               return update;
>
> ### }
>
> function btn_upgrade_onclick() {
>               var dealerID = "1";
>               var dlr = "1";
>               var dlrname = "abc";
>               var addr1 = "india";
>               var addr2 = "delhi";
>               var addr3 = "delhi";
>               var mobno = "1234567890";
>               var stat = "";
>               var DlrLan = "123";
>               var Dlrddd = "1123";
>               $.ajax({
>                   type: "POST",
>                   url: "AutoComplete.asmx/UpdateDealer",
>                   data: "{DlrId:'" + dealerID + "', DlrCode:'" + dlr + "', DlrName:'" + dlrname + "', Dlrad1:'" + addr1 + "' , Dlrad2:'" +
>   addr2 + "', Dlrad3:'" + addr3 + "', Dlrddd:'" + Dlrddd + "', DlrLan:'"
>   + DlrLan + "', DlrMob:'" + mobno + "'}",
>                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
>                   dataType: "json", 
>                   success: function(data) {
>                       $("#drp_support").get(0).options.length = 0;
>                       $("#drp_support").get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "0");
>                       $("#drp_support").unbind("change");
>                       alert(data);
>                       $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
>                           $("#drp_support").get(0).options[$("#drp_support").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
>                       });
>
> ```
>                 $("#drp_support").bind("change", function() {  
>                     sprtengId = $(this).val();  
>                 });  
>             },  
>             error: function() {  
>                 alert("Error");  
>             }  
>         });  
>     }
> ```